# Shape of Isoprofit Curves for Strategic Complements

Tags: microeconomics, producer-theory

Two goods are strategic complements if:
$$\frac{\partial \pi_1}{\partial q_2}>0\;\text{and}\;\frac{\partial \pi_2}{\partial q_1}>0$$
The image below is a picture of best response functions and isoprofit curves for strategic complements

[image]

I understand why the BR curves are upward sloping, but I am struggling to understand why the isoprofit curves are shaped the way they are. Can anyone give me the intuition behind the shape of these isoprofit curves?

Comment: It looks like each firm prefers that they make more profit with each of them producing some of their good, rather than one firm making a lot and the other firm making a little. So a sort of "preference for the middle" like in Cobb-Douglass utility.